# Test application lay-out for low resolution (winform)

Tags: winforms, testing, resolution

Our firm is investigating in acquiring 22" monitors for our development team.
The only current issue is that our users will be using smaller screens.

We tried using a screen-grid tool (gridmove and nvidia's utils), but they are not entirely realistic.

How do you test winform application layouts on a resolution lower then your screen's optimal resolution without constantly switching resolutions?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Did you find any?

Answer (score 2):

Most applications I have worked on have been using a menu. In those cases I have added a menu with items like 1024x768, 1280x1024, 1400x900, etc. This special menu is only added to program in debug mode.

```
#if DEBUG
AddDebugMenu(mainMenuStrip);
#endif

private void AddDebugMenu(MenuStrip menuStrip) {
  ToolStripMenuItem debugMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem("Debug");
  menuStrip.Items.Add(debugMenu);
  debugMenu.DropDownItems.Add("1024x768", null, delegate { Size = new Size(1024, 768);});
  debugMenu.DropDownItems.Add("1280x1024", null, delegate { Size = new Size(1280, 1024);});
}
```

This of course if the AddDebugMenu() is placed in the main form class.